# trigger to send an email to owner in contact object

Tags: email-alert

Can anyone help me how to write the trigger to send an email when a contact is created. Or can we do this with the work flow in salesforce.

Regards,
Raju.

Comment: Hi Raju, welcome to SE. Have you tried to solve this yourself? are you facing any issue?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Workflow is perfect for this scenario. Have an email template created before hand and select the template in Email Alert creation as workflow action.

Answer (score 0):

trigger option if you want to go with trigger only

Create trigger

```
trigger SendEmail on Contact (after insert) {

  List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lst = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
  for(Contact objContact: Trigger.New)
  {
     Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
     semail.setTemplateId('Your Email Template Id');
     semail.setTargetObjectId(objContact.ownerId);
     semail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
     lst.add(semail);
  }
      Messaging.sendEmail(lst);
}
```

Comment: you need to use setTargetObjectId(objContact.ownerId) target object to ownerid this will send email to owner

Comment: You shouldn't use code to send an email. Use a workflow rule.